Scroll snapping doesn't work well with mouse. Using mouse, the page gets scrolled abruptly
I am using full section scrolling using scroll snapping. If I scroll through touchpad, it is smooth. But if I use mouse and make the scroll wheel scroll just a bit, then it scrolls with jerk/speed.
I have searched through various stack overflow posts related to this but it did not help. They told to use  scroll-behavior: smooth; for solving the mouse scroll with jerk. But none of the solutions worked. Can anyone help me to solve this problem. Also I tried to do it using pure js but it was getting problematic one or the other way.
Here is the codepen link of the same code:
https://codepen.io/Utsav-Raithatha/pen/RwXzMyy


.scroll-container {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.scroll-area {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.scroll-container,
.scroll-area {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.scroll-area:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.scroll-area:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.scroll-area:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
}

.scroll-area:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: black;
}
<div class="scroll-container">
  <div class="scroll-area">1</div>
  <div class="scroll-area">2</div>
  <div class="scroll-area">3</div>
  <div class="scroll-area">4</div>
</div>



I tried using scroll-behavior: smooth; but it did not work and same problem was occurring.

this is default behavior, I don't think css is going to cut it. You might need to manually take control of the scroll with mouse wheel and set its speed

How to set the mouse wheel speed? Because I have searched in google, but it says that controlling mouse speed is not possible.

Sorry I mean the speed of the scroll, not the mouse. Basically you cancel the mouse event and simply scroll to the section with the .scrollBy() or .scrollTo() whenever users scroll with mouse

Can you please tell me how can I do that, because I am not able to do that.

Did you use AI tool with my suggestion on your codepen link? It seems to somewhat solve your problem, though you should remember that you're overriding the default behavior, which might become a problem later. Simplicity is the best, don't give your self a headache

I used AI tools but somehow some other problems occurs like it scrolls multiple pages with single scroll. But yes thank you for answering my query. I think I should better use the default one.
